# msedgedriver and msedge issue

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge

Recently edge updated in new version 120.0.2210.121 and I am using VBA-Selenium API and getting an error message:

WebDriver command failed (Status = 13)
{"sessionId":"f67309aed838a35826b27da4ee46f14d","status":13,"value":{"message":"unknown error: cannot find msedge binary\n (Driver info: msedgedriver=120.0.2210.121 (6086ec26a02a23b672367)

earlier macro is working fine please look it this if it is possible where is the issue in API?

for VBA Selenium API Refer to code link - https://github.com/sdkn104/VBA-Selenium

I have updated msedgedriver as per my msedge current version. again installed and repair msedge but issue are remain.

Comment: Please post your code including the URL you are querying so we can test this.

Comment: I have huge, big code  so please refer to below link

https://github.com/sdkn104/VBA-Selenium/blob/master/SeleniumDriver.cls

Comment: earlier the macro with this code working fine but recently Edge updated and getting an error message, the below one:

WebDriver command failed (Status = 13) {"sessionId":"f67309aed838a35826b27da4ee46f14d","status":13,"value":{"message":"unknown error: cannot find msedge binary\n (Driver info: msedgedriver=120.0.2210.121 (6086ec26a02a23b672367)

Comment: This is not a problem with edgedriver, it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please update to the latest version of edge to see if this issue persists.
Also, for this error you can specify the path to edge binary like this:

```
driver.SetBinary “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe”
```